# Create a dynamic RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is is possible to create a RewriteRule that conatins a dynamic parameter (partial url)?

Here is the existing Rewrite:

```
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_NAME}  ^dashdiscovery-dev.site.com
RewriteRule ^/?auth/?$ https://osso-stg.site.com/opensso/idpssoinit?realm=/sitenet&iPSPCookie=yes&RelayState=app=tableau,appURI=/views&NameIDFormat=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress&metaAlias=/sitenet/externalidpv2&spEntityID=server.site.com&binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST  [L,R]
```

What I need to to get the full address that is requested and put it in the Rewrite appURI= parameter dynamically.

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond  %{SERVER_NAME}  ^dashdiscovery-dev.site.com(/view/page7)
    RewriteRule ^/?auth/?$ https://osso-stg.site.com/opensso/idpssoinit?realm=/sitenet&iPSPCookie=yes&RelayState=app=tableau,appURI=(**/view/page7**)&NameIDFormat=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress&metaAlias=/sitenet/externalidpv2&spEntityID=server.site.com&binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST  [L,R]
```

But I also need it to redirect to just /views is there isn't any additional parameter after the site name RewriteCond  %{SERVER_NAME}  ^dashdiscovery-dev.site.com

Edit to provide more info about the expected urls:

dashdiscovery-dev.site.com

- would need to have appURI=/views in the Rewrite

dashdiscovery-dev.site.com/views/ResourceManagerDashboardv10-3-15-13_bkup/4DemandvsBooking

- would need to have appURI=/views/ResourceManagerDashboardv10-3-15-13_bkup/4DemandvsBooking in the Rewrite

dashdiscovery.site.com/views/OpsPipeline/PipelineDash

- would need to have appURI=/views/OpsPipeline/PipelineDash in the Rewrite

not all URLs will be only 2 levels past /views, but they *should* all have /views

Comment: How about you give us examples of the URLs you want to capture so we can better assist you with your issue? From your examples its unclear what you're asking not to mention wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For `dashdiscovery-dev.site.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashdiscovery-dev\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://osso-stg.site.com/opensso/idpssoinit?realm=/sitenet&iPSPCookie=yes&RelayState=app=tableau,appURI=/views&NameIDFormat=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress&metaAlias=/sitenet/externalidpv2&spEntityID=server.site.com&binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST  [L,R]
```

For everything else:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dashdiscovery-dev\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(views/.*)$ https://osso-stg.site.com/opensso/idpssoinit?realm=/sitenet&iPSPCookie=yes&RelayState=app=tableau,appURI=/$1&NameIDFormat=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress&metaAlias=/sitenet/externalidpv2&spEntityID=server.site.com&binding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST  [L,R]
```

The `$1` in the rule's target backreferences the `(views/.*)` regex match.